# Forked driver instance never quits

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have problems with running multiple browser windows in Protractor. 
The sample code tested is written out below: I fork the browser to get a new window and to some tests. When i write input into the original browser, the forked one shouldn't have that input. 
Everything works fine except that afterwards the forked browser never shuts down and some kind of error message is written to the output.

**My test suite:**

```
'use strict';

describe('testing', function () {
    it('should work', function () {
        browser.get('http://angularjs.org');
        var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        element(by.name('as_q')).sendKeys('search');
        expect(browser2.element(by.name('as_q')).getText()).toBe('');
    });
});
```

And this is my config:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000',
    specs: 'test.spec.js',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

And this is what is written out to stdout when running protractor in the terminal:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://<my-ip-adress>:54721/wd/hub
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 8.755 seconds
Shutting down selenium standalone server.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
From: Task: WebDriver.quit()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:360:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.quit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:443:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:59:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/array/array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:552:16)
    at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue [as _onTimeout] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:125:21)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Using Protractor 2.0.0.

Why isn't the forked driver instance quitted like the ordinary browser is. Do I have to close it down manually before the selenium server terminates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly quit the second session, protractor takes care of closing only the main one.

So, just add:

`broswer2.quit();`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is you are still trying to quit the Original driver, not the forked one.

Rather than forking, could you not do something like

```
browser = new Browser();
```

hopefully with this your 'new' browser should quit.

Another option as a solution would be using the WebDriver's driver.switchTo().frame() method

You can select using a;

1. A number. (0 based index)
2. A name or ID.
3. A previously found WebElement.   (maybe the easiest for you)

Once you have switched, you Should be able to quit.

Comment: Is not answering the question, he is asking how to it with `forkNewDriverInstance`

Comment: The reason it is failing is exactly as I said, he is quitting the original browser not the forked one.  

Although he can explicitly quit the forkNewDriverInstance that isnt actually the best solution for what he wants to achieve and why he forked it (from the comment).  A better solution is to use a single driver instance and switch frames (to avoid call conflicts) and quit the frames he no longer requires.

Comment: Switching frames is not a solution when you are checking interaction within the same website, but in different sessions (account irl).

Comment: "I fork the browser to get a new window and to some tests." sounds to me like he Does want a different session...  

Anyway, hope the comments you find a solution Olov

Comment: I want to get a new window with a new session. And this is possible by forking - I've tested that. But perhaps your solution works as well, Adurbe. I will have to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Since I'm just hacking on a side project [I've just forked protractor and commented out the piece of code that stops the server prematurely.](https://github.com/thpongue/protractor/commit/164771fda1e70fba3db265ed325c08ebb317877d)

```
//self.server_.stop().then(function() {
       deferred.resolve();
//});
```

Not pretty but for my simple project it's done the trick.

Apologies that my first SO comment is such a terrible hack :-) maybe this will provide a clue for someone with a little more protractor knowledge than me.

Comment: could you edit your answer and add the modification you made?

Comment: there's a github link in my answer

Comment: Yes i know but your answer qualifies for what is called a "Link only answer" which is rarely welcome on SO. You should always add the code / some explanation / description whatever the content of your linked site is.

Comment: I'm offering this as an incomplete answer. I spent an hour or so in the  Protractor codebase and got lucky, shared what little I know and invited others with more Protractor experience to help. The other answers I've read here are on the wrong track entirely.